# Complexity of merge auxiliary procedure

Tags: algorithm, sorting, merge, mergesort, array-merge

In Cormen's "Introduction To Algorithms" Book they use this procedure called "Merge"

[image]

It is auxiliary for the well-known Merge Sort algorithm

[image]

The book states that the "Merge" procedure has a θ(n) | n = r-p+1 complexity; I want to prove this, and so far have come up with this analysis (I intend to model the worst case scenario)

[image]

However, lines 12-18 are a little tough to come up with, since in order to find the worst case, I have to compute too many options and possibilities in my head, and it's a little overwhelming; So far, I think that the worst case occurs when all elements in the Left (L) subarray are bigger than all elements in right (R) subarray, but I'm not sure.

Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance.

edit: In the book, nonetheless, they don't take into account lines 13-18; could you tell me why is this? and how can I come up with the complexity w/o taking those lines into account?

Comment: Please don't use images of text in your question. Even pseudo-code should be formatted in code blocks. See [an image of your code is not helpful](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode).

Comment: They ignore 13-18 because those lines run in constant time. There are no loops, no calls to other functions, no recursive calls. So nothing in those lines depends on the size of the array.

Comment: Do you know where can I find the criteria on when it is right to ignore lines of code like that?

Answer (score 0):

It's much easier to prove if you use a "charge" argument.  Note that the last loop assigns `p - r + 1` elements in `A`.  Now just go through the rest of the code and "charge" each constant unit of work to one those elements. As long as each gets a constant maximum number of charges - and that's easy to show - the algorithm has run time `Omega(p - r + 1) = Omega(n)`.